# Cannot use a C++/CLI DLL unless visual studio is installed

Tags: c#, visual-c++, c++-cli

### Intro

I'm Developing a tool that can interpret and use API Blueprints.

I created a new console app, added [SnowCrash.NET nuget package](https://github.com/brutski/snowcrash-dot-net-wrapper) and wrote this code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        snowcrashCLR.Blueprint blueprint;
        snowcrashCLR.Result result;

        var path = args.Length > 1 ? args[1] : @"c:\";

        snowcrashCLR.SnowCrashCLR.parse(path, out blueprint, out result);
        if (result != null)
        {
            var warnings = result.GetWarningsCs();
            foreach (var warning in warnings)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", warning.code, warning.message);
            }
        }
    }
```

### Problem

When I deployed my code (copied the bin folder) to a different computer than my development environment, I get a FileNotFoundException pointing to SnowCrash.dll

here is a snapshop from the error message:

> Could not load file or assembly 'snowcrashCLR.DLL' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.

### Details:

```
[FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'snowcrashCLR.DLL' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.]
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +34
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +152
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection) +77
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection) +16
   System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString) +28
```

### What I've tried so far

- I used sysinternal procmon on both machines to compare and it looks like my dev machine (which runs fine) is loading this DLL:

> **Load Image**
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualC.STLCLR\v4.0_2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualC.STLCLR.dll

- My computer, which the application works fine on, has these runtimes installed

```
MS Visual C++ 2005 Redist (x64)
MS Visual C++ 2008 Redist (x64) 9.0.30729.4148
MS Visual C++ 2008 Redist (x64) 9.0.30729.6161
MS Visual C++ 2008 Redist (x86) 9.0.30729.4148
MS Visual C++ 2008 Redist (x86) 9.0.30729.6161
MS Visual C++ 2010 x64 Redist - 10.0.40219
MS Visual C++ 2013 x64 Redist - 12.0.30501
MS Visual C++ 2013 x86 Redist - 12.0.30501
```

- On the computer that had the error (did not work), I installed the same identical list of runtimes above, but that did not solve the problem or made it work.
- I installed visual studio on that computer, that did not work previously, and when I tried my application and it worked

### Your help is greatly appreciated if you have better knowledge or battle scars with a similar issue.

Comment: Did you try setting the 32bit parameter on the application pool to true?

Comment: I did try that (enable 32 bit) and did not help under IIS 8.0, but that made it work under IIS 7.x though.

Comment: Do you have to host under IIS 8.0? What about a self-hosted API using OWIN? You can create the service using TopShelf and this package: https://github.com/dennisroche/Topshelf.Owin/

Comment: The plan is to allow this to run as an ASP.net module and be part of the same website, so IIS is by choice here. I was not trying to create a stand-alone tool.

Comment: Are you deploying the Debug build, or the Release build? They use different runtimes, and the debug runtime is not available as a redistributable.

Comment: I will check if debug or release, but how can I tell? Because my c++ dll comes in a nugget package and I don't know how it's built.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood, I thought the C++ DLL was yours, not NuGet. Regardless, release compiles will be linked against "MSVCR<version>.DLL", debug will be linked against "MSVCR<version>D.DLL" (the trailing 'D' stands for 'Debug'). Download the dependency walker from http://www.dependencywalker.com/ to see what it links against.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By doing lots of digging on the inter-webs I found that there was a missing dependency that the SnowCrash DLL needs in order to run, which was Visual C++ runtime 2012 x86.

since its a mixed (managed CLR + Native) DLL, it needs the C++ MFC library, that comes with the VC++ runtime. and it must be the right version in order to run properly.

Installing the runtime from [this MSDN URL](http://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=30679) onto the target computer solved my problem.